# Office Web App Sharepoint 2013 external access issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

today some users reported that they cant access any OWAS features externally, unless they are dialed into the VPN. These features have worked in the past (embedded documents and preview / edit) but now it just says

**Sorry Something went wrong.**

sorry you don't have access.

everything internally still works fine + VPN users its just internet users

i am the only administrator of SharePoint and OWAS and nothing has been changed, by me at least.

i checked the services and also reboot the OWAS server to see if that would resolve the problem, but never.

i have collected some ULS logs and done some research,

```
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005

WopiFrame: User does not have access to document. Action is EmbedView.
```

it seems that users are changed to "anonymous" rather than there account.

my OWAS is not published through a TMG, however my SharePoint is, i could publish my OWAS through the TMG but it wasn't required in the past so i don't see why it should be needed now.

i have seen restarting the Distributed Cache service can resolve some of these types of issues but can this not result in data loss?

wondered if anyone had came across this or had any suggestions.

many thanks

Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know for SP 2010 it didn't matter but in SP 2013, you need to have your OWAS published through TMG as well for it to work correctly for external users.  This is because SharePoint just iframes in a url to the OWAS (see fiddler trace screenshot below).

[image: Fiddler Trace]

But I would not expect a permission error to be the result of having this not configured correctly.  It almost sounds like the user can't authenticate to the OWAS server and thus the claim can't be correctly impersonated to the SharePoint server to receive the file.  Maybe take a look as the IIS logs on your SharePoint box and see if the request for the file is authenticated or not.

Are there any dns changes that would make it so your owas can't connect to the sharepoint server?  If you RDP into one of your owas servers, can you open the browser and connect to the a site on the sharepoint box?

Comment: thanks for the reply, ill have to check out fiddler i ever used it before i just stick to the ULS log outputs in ULS viewer, ill also try the IIS logs and get back to you, many thanks

there have been no DNS or IP changes as far as i can see OWAS A records are in the correct zones pointing to the IP of the OWA server

cheers

Comment: have i missed some configuration steps perhaps, do i need to add a (A) record on my public DNS resolving to the OWAS server so it can resolve the external URL?

Comment: Yes, probably an A record on your public DNS resolving to TMG which then publishes your OWAS server.

Comment: yep was the A record, the thing that threw me was that users said it was working previously but i cant see how it ever was as this A record has been always missing.

cheers

Comment: Cool, if my answer helped you resolve this, please up vote it and mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks.